# Error message Daemon failed to start V.0.18.1.2 Windows 10

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, daemon, full-node, error-log

```
2022-12-01 05:14:51.471 11112   INFO    logging contrib/epee/src/mlog.cpp:273   New log categories: *:WARNING,net:FATAL,net.http:FATAL,net.ssl:FATAL,net.p2p:FATAL,net.cn:FATAL,daemon.rpc:FATAL,global:INFO,verify:FATAL,serialization:FATAL,daemon.rpc.payment:ERROR,stacktrace:INFO,logging:INFO,msgwriter:INFO
2022-12-01 05:14:51.498 11112   INFO    global  src/daemon/main.cpp:296 Monero 'Fluorine Fermi' (v0.18.1.2-release)
2022-12-01 05:14:51.499 11112   INFO    global  src/daemon/protocol.h:53    Initializing cryptonote protocol...
2022-12-01 05:14:51.500 11112   INFO    global  src/daemon/protocol.h:58    Cryptonote protocol initialized OK
2022-12-01 05:14:51.501 11112   INFO    global  src/daemon/core.h:64    Initializing core...
2022-12-01 05:14:51.504 11112   INFO    global  src/cryptonote_core/cryptonote_core.cpp:523 Loading blockchain from folder F:\monero.pharoah\lmdb ...
2022-12-01 05:14:59.843 11112   ERROR   cn  src/cryptonote_basic/cryptonote_format_utils.cpp:1544   Failed to parse block from blob
2022-12-01 05:14:59.877 11112   INFO    global  src/daemon/protocol.h:75    Stopping cryptonote protocol...
2022-12-01 05:14:59.877 11112   INFO    global  src/daemon/protocol.h:79    Cryptonote protocol stopped successfully
2022-12-01 05:14:59.878 11112   ERROR   daemon  src/daemon/main.cpp:364 Exception in main! Failed to parse block from blob retrieved from the db
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a corrupted database. See [issue comments](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/issues/7023) for remedies.